# UIbutton inside UILabel text

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to design a `UIlabel` with clickable `UIButton`'s inside like in the image below.

[image]

The idea here is that I am getting some text which contains some markers and when that marker appears I have to draw the button instead of the text inside the `UILabel`. **These buttons should be clickable**.

I have tried to accomplish it with `AttributedText` to `UILabel` but with attributed text, I am not able to give the extra spacing for the button also the corner radius and the border color don't look as good as they should be, but the bigger problem is that I am not able to get the correct position of the UILabel tap, I guess maybe because I am using a custom font. I tried this approach: https://samwize.com/2016/03/04/how-to-create-multiple-tappable-links-in-a-uilabel/ to get the tapped characters but its always a few characters off and when the text gets bigger it becomes more inaccurate.

I think there are two approaches to it

1. Create a `UILabel` and use attributed text to give the proper formatting and a `UILabel` tap gesture to handle and locate the position of the click. (I have tried this approach and it's not very successful)
2. Maybe create a custom view where we add text to the view and the buttons whenever the marker appears, I am not sure how to accomplish this but with approach, I believe we can get away with handling the

   tap Gestures because UiButton already will give us the tap event.

   ```
   class RQCommentaryLabel: UICrimsonLabel {


     var commentaryTextProvider: CommentaryTextProvider?
     private var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?

     override init (fontType: FontType, textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle, fontWeight: FontWeight, text: String?) {

     super.init(fontType: fontType, textStyle: textStyle, fontWeight: fontWeight, text: text)
     tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedOnLabel(_ :)))

     self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     tapGesture?.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
     self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func renderCommentryText(textProvider: CommentaryTextProvider) {
     self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
     self.commentaryTextProvider = textProvider
     let formattedtext = textProvider.commentaryRenderedText()
     self.attributedText = formattedtext
    }

   @objc func tappedOnLabel(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     let dict = commentaryTextProvider?.commentaryData() ?? [:]
     for(key, value) in dict {
        let location = gesture.location(in: self)
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: self, inRange: value, location: location) {
           print("Tapped :\(key)")
        }
     }
   }
   ```

   UIGestureRecognizer Extension

   ```
    extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

   func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange, location: CGPoint) -> Bool {
       // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
       let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
       let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: label.bounds.size)
       let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)


       // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
       layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
       textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

       // Configure textContainer
       textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
       textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
       textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines

       let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

       return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
   }
   ```

   }

Helper class

```
class CommentaryTextProvider {
    
    private let commentarytext: String
    private var commentaryRanges = [String: NSRange]()
    
    
    init(commentarytext: String) {
        self.commentarytext = commentarytext
    }
    
    func commentaryRenderedText() -> NSAttributedString {
        let matches = commentaySymbolMatches(text: commentarytext)
        let removedString = commentarytext.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: " ")
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: removedString)
        let shadow = NSShadow()
        shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2.0
        
        commentaryRanges = [:]
        for match in matches {
            attributedString.addAttributes([
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.RQColors.switchColor,
                .baselineOffset: 3,
                .textEffect: NSAttributedString.TextEffectStyle.letterpressStyle,
                .font: UIFont.fontfor(.englishNormal, weight: .bold, style: .body),
                .shadow: shadow
            ], range: match.range)
            let subStr = (attributedString.string as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
            commentaryRanges[subStr] = match.range
        }
        
        return attributedString
    }
    
    func commentaryData() -> [String: NSRange] {
        return commentaryRanges
    }
    
    private func commentaySymbolMatches(text: String) -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        let pattern = "\\[[^\\[]*\\]"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        return regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
    }
```

Any idea how I can achieve this behavior? Thanks

Comment: You can indeed add tappable links in a label, but you can't insert buttons in a label as you describe.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `UITextView`, `NSLinkAttributeName` & custom "rendering", with `CoreText`, `NSLayoutManager`. It's some work though.